# mysql_query ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have problem, I would like to make update when hash is same. **hash** is **unique** at table. I cant find the right way to do this.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO shop_product_search3_muokattu2 
            (id, hash, product_name, type, manufacturer, mini_products) VALUES
            (NULL, '".$hash."', '".$row['product_name']."', '".$row['type']."', '". $row['manufacturer']."', '".$row['mini_products']."') 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY 
               UPDATE mini_products += VALUES('".$mini_products."') ") 
            or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: When I try to add new $row['mini_products'] to behind of old $row['mini_products'] when hash matches. I dont know to update database like that. I just made it to add new to replace old data, but I want to make them add together. mini_products = '".$row['mini_products']."' ") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Obligatory: If this is PHP (which it looks like), mysql_query is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Yeah its PHP, I try to search right way to do this.

Comment: MySQLi or PDO_MySQL Are both referenced in the link

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO shop_product_search3_muokattu2(id, hash, product_name, type, manufacturer, mini_products) 
    VALUES (NULL, '".$hash."', '".$row['product_name']."', '".$row['type']."', '". $row['manufacturer']."', '".$row['mini_products']."') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mini_products += VALUES('".$mini_products."'
```

I believe you have a problem with the `on duplicate key update` statement.  The argument to `VALUES` should be a column name.  Alternatively, you can put the value in directly.  So, either of the following should work:

```
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mini_products += VALUES(mini_products)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mini_products += $mini_products
```

As a note:  I assume that `+=` works, but I would write these as:

```
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mini_products = coalesce(mini_products, 0) + VALUES(mini_products)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mini_products = coalesce(mini_products, 0) + $mini_products
```

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mini_products = mini_products + '".$row['mini_products']."' ") or die(mysql_error());  when I try add them database only show me result of 0.

Comment: I dont have any clue how to make update statement. It should push new data with old to mini_products column. And I am writing PHP.